# External HDD not detected on HP Laptop 15s-eq1

Tags: dual-boot, usb, hard-drive

I connected an external hard disk drive (HGST 500GB) to my ubuntu laptop yesterday, the hdd took some time but connected successfully and I transferred a few of my files to it. I had one more hard disk (Seagate 1TB) which I wanted to test, so I took the old hard disk out (the hgst one) and connected the seagate 1tb hard disk to the HDD connector, after that the laptop did not detect the hard disk, but the LED on the hdd connector was still working. So I thought that the hard disk must be damaged internally.

Then when I connected my old hard disk, the seagate one, to the hdd connector, my laptop did not detect the hard disk...The hard disk connector LED was still functional, that means that it was receiving sufficient power...But just not detected by my laptop. I tried connecting both the hard disks with other laptop and they both work perfectly there, means there's something wrong with my system. I booted into windows (I have dual booth Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS and Windows 11) where i faced the same issue, even windows did not detect the hard disk...Then I found out that the black chip on the HDD connector (which I believe to be the brain of the connector that transfers power from the usb port to the hard disk) was heating up, it wasn't heating up when used on my other laptop but this one. I can figure out that this means that the hdd connector is receiving power but unable to transfer it to the hard disk but somehow everything works on my other laptop which is actually older than this one. What could possibly be wrong? I tried entering my laptop's system diagnosis and ran a couple of tests on the USB port, then the seagate hard disk was functional! I could hear the original beeping sound that I had heard before when it was working on my laptop and the hdd connector LED was functional too! Maybe there is some power issue? The HDD is not getting enough power? How can I fix this in ubuntu?

Comment: Just because light is on, may not mean it has enough power to spin up drive. For external drives with laptops, you may not have enough power thru USB port. I had an old HDD what would not work in adapter, but SSD worked great. Better to have external power source for external HDD, or better still use external SSD.

Comment: @oldfred how do I get external power source for this specific hdd?

Comment: I only use SSD or flash drives (less so) for external drives. Have seen adapters with external power supply. Or a multiple port USB hub that can output more power. But you would have to check specs. My really old adapter had a SATA port and separate power connector.

Comment: I bought a new adapter and this one works alright, thank you! @oldfred